# Custom UISegmentedControl in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a custom UISegmentedControl (similar to [this one](https://github.com/kferrell/KFSegmentedControlExample)) and want to show its design in my storyboard.

I created this subclass:

CustomSegmentedControl.h

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CustomSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl

@end
```

CustomSegmentedControl.m

```
#import "CustomSegmentedControl.h"

@implementation CustomSegmentedControl

  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
      self = [super initWithFrame:frame];  
      if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
      } 
      return self;
    }

  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
      self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
      if (self) {
       [self commonInit];
      }
     return self;
    }

  - (void)commonInit {
     UIImage *backgroundOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentbk_off"];
     UIImage *backgroundOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentbk_on"];
     UIImage *separator = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_separator"];

     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                               self.frame.origin.y,
                               self.frame.size.width,
                               50.0);
     [self setFrame:frame];

     [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundOff
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal
                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundOn
                     forState:UIControlStateSelected
                   barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [self setDividerImage:separator
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [self setDividerImage:separator
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [self setDividerImage:separator
       forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
         rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  }

@end
```

I changed the class of the SegmentedControl to CustomSegmentedControl in my storyboard and, when I launch the app, the control looks like it should be. But in my storyboard has the regular UISegmentedControl appearance.

Is there anyway to match its real appearance in the storyboard?

Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's how you do it. First thing, you are on the right track by using `IB_DESIGNABLE`.

Second thing, you would need to create `IB_INSPECTABLE` properties for the things you want to control and render in the Storyboard, and create setters for them in your .m file.

What I've done is just a start, I am sure there is more that can be done here.

Attached code for your reference:

.h file:

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface CustomSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIImage *backgroundOff;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIImage *backgroundOn;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIImage *separator;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "CustomSegmentedControl.h"

@implementation CustomSegmentedControl

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setBackgroundOff:(UIImage *)backgroundOff
{
    _backgroundOff = backgroundOff;
    [self setBackgroundImage:self.backgroundOff
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

-(void) setBackgroundOn:(UIImage *)backgroundOn
{
    _backgroundOn = backgroundOn;
    [self setBackgroundImage:self.backgroundOn
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}

-(void) setSeparator:(UIImage *)separator
{
    _separator = separator;
    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}




- (void)commonInit {
    _backgroundOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentbk_off"];
    _backgroundOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segmentbk_on"];
    _separator = [UIImage imageNamed:@"segment_separator"];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                              self.frame.origin.y,
                              self.frame.size.width,
                              50.0);
    [self setFrame:frame];

    [self setBackgroundImage:self.backgroundOff
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setBackgroundImage:self.backgroundOn
                    forState:UIControlStateSelected
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self setDividerImage:self.separator
      forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal
        rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected
               barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

@end
```

And here's how it looks in the Interface builder:

[image]

The component now looks much closer to the actual implementation.

And as you can see now you have 3 new editable properties in the Attribute Inspector panel. I hope this is a good start and you take it from here :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Good question and glad to help :)